# Replacing inheritance with composition in generic classes?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, composition

I've been reading a lot about composition and trying to figure how I can refactor my inheritance tree using composition. Currently my class looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract string displayText { get; }

    public abstract List<Parameter> parameters { get; }

    public abstract void FireEvent();
}

public abstract class SubClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    private string _displayText;
    public override string displayText { get { return _displayText; } }

    private List<Parameter> _parameters;
    public override List<Parameter> parameters { get { return _parameters; } }

    private T _value;    // ADDED TO SUBCLASS
    public abstract Event<T> Evt { get; } // ADDED TO SUBCLASS

    public override void FireEvent()
    {
        Evt.Raise(_value);
    }
}

public class IntClass : SubClass<int>{}
public class StringClass : SubClass<string>{} // more subclasses like this
```

From my understanding, there is both inheritance and composition going on here.

SubClass **Has-A**: (Composition)

1. List of `Parameters`
2. Field for `Event`
3. Behaviour of `Event<T>` which is called within it's own `FireEvent` method

SubClass **Is-A**: BaseClass (Inheritance)

IntClass/StringClass **Is-A**: SubClass & BaseClass

The reason for creating `BaseClass` is because I need polymorphic lists. This way I can create a `List<BaseClass>` and call `FireEvent()` on each element in the list and access the `displayText` and `List<Parameter>` in a loop.

In the future I will need a sub class which doesn't have an `Event` and a subclass which will accept a parameter in `FireEvent()`. Other variants might crop up.

How would I replace my current structure entirely with a composition based approach? Is it even doable?

Comment: Why would you want to?  So you don't break Liskov?

Comment: Isn't this better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com?

Comment: If you inherit a class then it's inheritance and when you store a different class as either field or property then it's composition. You should use either or both depending on your use-case and not follow one over the other.

Comment: You don't see the benefits of composition here. Because you have only 1 behavior (FireEvent()). Let's say if you got 5 methods in BaseClass, 10 more in SubClass. Then your IntCass and StringClass inherit 15 methods from above, but IntClass uses only 7 and StringClass uses only 2. Now imagine change 1 method in your BaseClass, you don't know if you beak anything. That's where you want to take your 15 methods and put into services (can be 1 service or many services)

Comment: @Alex-TinLe yes that is exactly my concern. I will be adding new behaviours in the future. I'm just not sure how to refactor this for that future flexibility. Could you elaborate on services and how that might look?

Comment: @rory.ap for future flexibility - as I'll have future variants with different attributes.

Comment: "The reason for creating BaseClass is because I need polymorphic lists." Use Interfaces.

Comment: @Nando building this in Unity which is unable to serialize interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In this example, you have 3 behaviors. Int uses 3, String uses only 2. If you put the code like this, when you change AnotherServiceB, you don't need to be worry about it break String (since String doesn't have that service)

```
public class FireEventService<T>
{
    private T _value;    // ADDED TO SUBCLASS
    public abstract Event<T> Evt { get; } // ADDED TO SUBCLASS

    public override void FireEvent()
    {
        Evt.Raise(_value);
    }
}

public class AnotherService
{

}

public class AnotherServiceB
{

}

public abstract class SubClass<T> : BaseClass
{
    private readonly FireEventService<T> _fireEventService;
    private readonly AnotherService _anotherService;

    private string _displayText;
    public override string displayText { get { return _displayText; } }

    private List<Parameter> _parameters;
    public override List<Parameter> parameters { get { return _parameters; } }

    public SubClass(FireEventService<T> fireEventService, AnotherService anotherService)
    {
        // All those services should use with interface and Dependency Injection
        _fireEventService = fireEventService;
        _anotherService = anotherService;
    }

    public void FireEvent() => _fireEventService.FireEvent();
}

public class IntClass : SubClass<int>
{
    private readonly AnotherServiceB _anotherServiceB;
    public IntClass(FireEventService<int> fireEventService, AnotherService anotherService, AnotherServiceB anotherServiceB)
        : base(fireEventService, anotherService)
    { }
    public void DoSomethingUsingServiceB()
    {
        //_anotherServiceB.DoSomething();
    }
}
public class StringClass : SubClass<string> 
{
    public StringClass(FireEventService<string> fireEventService, AnotherService anotherService)
        : base(fireEventService, anotherService)
    { }
}
```

Comment: how would polymorphic lists work in this case. If I create a List<BaseClass> and put an IntClass and StringClass in it, when looping over this list, I would need to check if a certain behaviour is available right? How would I do this check?

Comment: I think you misundertand polymorphism. The composition doesnt help you to do polymorphism. But interfaces do.

Comment: Yes still wrapping my head around these concepts. So I need to use interfaces along with composition to achieve what I'm trying to?